# Swift: How to specify class candidate to use for a static method call

Tags: swift, inheritance, static, ambiguous

Let's say we have two **Obj-C** classes like these:

```
Parent {
   + (void)doSomething {
      NSLog(@"%@", [self messageToDisplay]);
   }

   + (NSString *)messageToDisplay {
      return @"message_parent";
   }
}

Child: Parent {
   + (NSString *)messageToDisplay {
      return @"message_child";
   }
}
```

And this **Swift** code:

```
Child.doSomething()
```

It generates this error because Swift does not know which candidate to use, Child or Parent.

> Ambiguous use of 'doSomething()'
>   Found this candidate (Child)
>   Found this candidate (Parent)

How can we specify the candidate to use?

Many thanks.

Comment: I've tried this case, and recieved no error. `Child.doSomething()` put `message_child` in the console. Maybe your code provided is missing something from your real project?

Comment: To be honest that's a piece of code I invented from scratch. Our real project is more complex but the actual issue remains the same. However, I will try to do the same in a brand new project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it. I found the cause of this issue. We have one ObjC method called deleteObjectWithId in the parent class and another one (useless by the way) called deleteGroupWithId it the child class and when calling the delete(withId:) method from Swift there are in fact two candidates. Many thanks.